# Disable Email mangling on Refresh

Tags: email, security

I'm working on an ETL from Salesforce <--> SQLServer.

Every time I refresh a sandbox, it mangles the e-mail address of every user (example `"somedude@company.com"` becomes `"somedude=company.com@example.com"`.

This is a *huge* pain because e-mail addresses are used as a unique identifier in part of our database (please, no scolding comments for this; I didn't make the rules).

I tried writing a script that set all users' addresses back to the correct address, but that doesn't work because it sends an e-mail to every user asking to confirm the change, which each user has to open and click the confirmation link in order for the change to take effect. Which is simply impractical.

I understand the need for security, but this is a sandbox, and it exists for no other purpose than as a dev environment for me.

**Is there any way to either:**

1. Disable the auto-mangling of everyone's email address, or
2. Disable the requirement for each user to individually approve the e-mail address change back to an actual address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disable the auto-mangling of everyone's email address, or

No. This is a feature that is always on. [This idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LiwtAAC) suggests that salesforce.com should at least not mangle admin emails, which would help, but isn't yet available, and probably never will be.

> Disable the requirement for each user to individually approve the e-mail address change back to an actual address?

Kind of. You can ask for the [Disable Email Change Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003832) feature, which allows you to specify a domain name that everyone can change to without triggering change verification. However, this is still complicated, because you then have to (a) refresh/create a sandbox, (b) request this feature, and (c) update all email addresses for your users. Every. Single. Time.

---

Your best bet right now is to run a [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) to automatically request the email changes for all users you want to immediately after the refresh completes. Users will have a few days to verify the change to their email, and it's just one click. Keep in mind that the developer and developer pro sandboxes don't copy custom settings, so if you want a solution that works across all types, make sure you're using Custom Metadata instead.

Comment: Thank you! I'll get a ticket put in to support. It mentioned in the instructions that you can grant a blanket approval for the verification to disabled every time, so that will speed things up a little. Also, I already have a script written to fix everyone's e-mail address in bulk.